# CornerRadius don't set

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2

I'm trying to round the corners on the UIView in bottom left and bottom right. 
[image][image]

```
extension UIView {    
    func roundBottom(raduis: CGFloat){
        let maskPath1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.BottomRight, .BottomLeft],
                                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width: raduis, height: raduis))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPath1.CGPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }
}
```

And call `cell.bottomCorner.roundBottom(8)`

**But I get it:**

iPhone 5:

[image]

iPhone 6s:

[image]

iPhone 6s Plus:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to update the mask everytime the view changes its size, therefore ideally you should change it whenever `UIView.layoutSubviews` is called:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews();
   // update mask
}
```

It's not ideal to do it in an extension helper method. You should create a specific class to handle the size change.